# How do I display entries from multiple entry types?

Tags: entry-type

I have a 'teacher' channel section on my site. That channel has three entry types, 'teacher', 'demoTeacher' and 'guestTeacher' - how do I display entries from teacher and demoTeach combined? At the moment I'm showing one type like this:

```
{% for teacher in craft.entries.find({section: 'teacher', type: 'demoTeacher'}) %}
```

Secondly, how can I use a conditional that checks for entry type? I need do something like the following (pseudocode):

```
{% if entrytype is demoTeacher %}
    display read more button
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the ElementCriteriaModel's [`type`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#type) parameter to multiple values by passing it an [array](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#expressions) of entry type slugs:

```
{% set teachers = craft.entries.section('teacher').type(['teacher', 'demoTeacher']) %}
```

Use the [`type`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#type) property on the entry model to access its entry type in your conditional (also see [this list](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#properties) for other available properties).

```
{% for teacher in teachers %}

    {{ teacher.title }}

    {% if teacher.type == 'demoTeacher' %}
        ...
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks - that works. Any idea how to use a conditional to test for entry type?

Comment: Sure I have! :)

Answer (score 3):

I know an answer has been accepted for this question, but I wanted to provide another example for folks like me who seem to have a thick skull sometimes.

I have a "team" section which is a structure (the entries within this structure do not have their own urls). Within that structure, I have two different entry types. "Team Category" and "Team Member". This allows me to nest different team members under different categories.

For example,

```
Accounting
    - Bob Smith
Marketing
    - John Doe
```

Here is how I did that in my entry template:

```
{% set teamMembers = craft.entries.section('team').type(['teamCategory', 'teamMember']) %}
    {% for member in teamMembers %}
        <div class="team-member">
        {% if member.type == 'teamCategory' %}
            <h3>{{ member.title }}</h3> {# Accounting #}
        {% else %}
            <p>{{ member.title }}</p>  {# Bob Smith #}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```