# How to limit navigation by entry type

Tags: entries, elementcriteriamodel, entry-type

I couldn't find this anywhere so I thought I would post the answer. How do you limit the output of a navigation element to a specific entry type.

This question is explicitly for the navigation element - I only want to show a specific entry type in a navigation element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display entries from multiple entry types?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/how-do-i-display-entries-from-multiple-entry-types)

Answer (score 1):

Both of these work:

```
{% set sectionNamePages = craft.entries.section('sectionName').type('entryTypeA').level(1) %}
{% for page in sectionNamePages %}
    <li class="{{ page.id == entry.id ? 'active' }}">{{ page.getLink() }}</li>
{% endfor %}


{% set sectionNamePages = craft.entries.section('sectionName').level(1) %}
{% for page in sectionNamePages.type('entryTypeA') %}
    <li class="{{ page.id == entry.id ? 'active' }}">{{ page.getLink() }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```